# Projeto não executa, erro "404 - Not Found"

Tags: java, wildfly, primefaces-3.5

Estou usando JAVa java JPA, com Wildfly e Primefaces e o banco estou usando o Mysql. Estou com

Tenho todas as camadas ja configuradas (view(xhtml),DAO,Entidade,MB). O datasouce do wildfly esta está configurado corretamente, mantendo a comunicação com o banco 100%.

Quando eu vou rodar o projeto ele acusa "404 - Not Found" e aparenemente o console nao exibe nada de anormal. Creio que seja erro na configuração de ambiente mas nao estou conseguindo identificar.

Segue o meu web.xml:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: sem postar o log fica complicado ajudar.

Comment: Consegui resolver! obrigado